# Оплата через PayPal laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-api

Я интегрировал PayPal Api на свой сайт. Всё работает как нужно.
Снимаются деньги с тестового счёта и зачисляются на тестовый бизнес счёт.

Но вот в чём проблема. Я решил проверить, что будет если на счету денег нет.
Операция прошла успешно. Деньги с тестового счёта не списались, так как там 0, но я проверил тестовый счёт, на который приходят деньги и они пришли.

как такое может быть, может подскажите какое-то решение.

Comment: Да так можно здорово обогатиться. Преведите себе с пустого счета миллионов десять долларов, снимите их с тестового счета и поезжайте в Мексику. Говорят, там Интерпол плохо работает. :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 В том то и дело, что с тестового счёта деньги снимаются и переводятся на другой тестовый счёт. Не выдаёт никакуб ошибку, что мол денег нет. Может ли это происходить из-за тестовых счетов?
И если будут реальные деньги, то снятие не произойдёт?

Comment: `то снятие не произойдёт?` главное, чтобы зачисления были =)

Comment: Вы меня извините за мои вопросы, может быть глупые, но я только начал разбираться.

Вы пишите, главное, чтобы зачисления были. Но откуда будут зачисления если на тестовом балансе от куда должны сняться деньги их нет, но на баланс продавца всё равно зачисляется сумма?